# Run-Time optimization (Python)

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to solve a problem on codechef called "Snake Eating". https://www.codechef.com/SDPCB21/problems/SNAKEEAT . Here is the solution that I came up with

```
try:
T = int(input())
for t in range(T):
    N, Q = tuple(input().split())
    N, Q = int(N), int(Q)
    L = list(input().split())
    for i in range(len(L)):
        L[i] = int(L[i])
    
    K = []
    
    for i in range(Q):
        K.append(input())
        
    for i in range(len(K)):
        K[i] = int(K[i])
    
    for q in range(Q):
        def solution(N, Q, K, L):
            
            x = K[q]
            L_temp = list(L)
            
            count = 0
            
            for element in L_temp:
                if element >= x:
                    L_temp.remove(element)
                    count += 1
                    
            L_temp.sort()
            
            while not (len(L_temp) - 1 < x - L_temp[-1]):
                for i in range(x - L_temp[-1]):
                    L_temp.pop(0)
                L_temp.pop(-1)
                count += 1
                    
            return count
            
        print(solution(N, Q, K, L))
    
    
except:
    pass
```

When I submitted my code. It shows time limit exceeded. Can someone tell me how can I optimize my code to achieve under 10 seconds runtime?

Comment: maybe cuz of the time you took to input the inputs, maybe...

Answer (score 0):

This is contains some things that could be done better.

```
     def solution(N, Q, K, L):
        
        x = K[q]
        L_temp = list(L)
        
        count = 0
        
        for element in L_temp:
            if element >= x:
                L_temp.remove(element)
                count += 1
                
        L_temp.sort()
        
        while not (len(L_temp) - 1 < x - L_temp[-1]):
            for i in range(x - L_temp[-1]):
                L_temp.pop(0)
            L_temp.pop(-1)
            count += 1
                
        return count
```

This loop is quadratic:

```
for element in L_temp:
    if element >= x:
        L_temp.remove(element)
        count += 1
```

As we are making a copy of a list and then counting the items that are greater than x. One can do that in linear time

```
L_temp = [element for element in L if element < x]
count = len(L) - len(L_temp)
```

This loop:

```
while not (len(L_temp) - 1 < x - L_temp[-1]):
     for i in range(x - L_temp[-1]):
          L_temp.pop(0)
     L_temp.pop(-1)
     count += 1
```

Doesn't actually need to mutate L_temp. It can operate instead on two indexes i and j.

```
i = 0
j = len(L_temp) - 1
while not (j - i) < x - L_temp[j]:
      i += x - L_temp[j] - 1
      j -= 1
      count += 1
```

There might be a min(0, ) call on the line that adds to i.

Comment: Hey thank you so much... I Tried this method but got TLE. Finally after a bit more research my solution got accepted using Binary search. And one correction. You wrote only "while" instead of "while not"